# SQL date Statement

Tags: sql, date, filter

I need some help figuring out and SQL Statement.

I know what I want I just cant express it.

Im using php, so it doesnt need to be exclusivly SQL, its to act as a filter.

Pseudo code

```
$query="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 'TIS'  is not older than 2 days or empty  = ''$ORDER"; }
```

TIS in the name of the column in my table were I store dates in this format `03-12-09` (d,m,y).
The `$ORDER` is for ordering the values based on values from other fields not dates.

Im looking at

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
WHERE day_of_order >
(SELECT DATEADD(day,-30, (SELECT MAX(day_of_order) FROM orders)) AS "-30 Days");
```

But i dont quite think im on the rigth track with this.

Thanks

Comment: Which SQL RDBMS is this?

Comment: Im using MySql. Im developing on my local machine with MAMP.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend changing the datatype of the TIS field so it is an actual date. Storing it as a string in dd-mm-yy format makes it much more difficult to filter or sort data according to how old it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was pretty lost in all this.

How did it got solved:

- First I understood that the Statement I was using was not supported by MySql thanks to eligthment from Bob Jarvis.

_ Second In a comment by vincebowdren wich "strongly" adviced me to change the data type on that field to `Date` wich indeed I had not, it was a string.

It was pretty Dumb for me to try using SQL operations for Dates on a field that had String values.

So I just RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

and:

`mysql> SELECT something FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date_col;`

Then proceeded to change the field value to date.

and this is my perfectly working query:

`$query="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) <= TIS OR TIS = 0000-00-00 $ORDER "; }`

I would like to thank the posters for their aid.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE COALESCE(TIS, SYSDATE) > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' DAY
  $ORDER
```

I don't know what database you're using - the above uses Oracle's method of dealing with time intervals.  If you're using SQL Server the following should be close:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE COALESCE(TIS, GETDATE()) > DATEADD(Day, -2, GETDATE())
  $ORDER
```

In MySQL try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE COALESCE(TIS, NOW()) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAYS)
  $ORDER
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: OK, then try SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE COALESCE(TIS, NOW()) > DATE_SUB(NOW, INTERVAL 2 DAYS) ORDER BY $ORDER

Comment: I get nothing. To organize this. - `ORDER BY` isnt necessary as it included in `$ORDER`. - Im still not sure what format for the value is expected to be present oin `TIS`. - What does mean `COALESCE`? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried running my query directy and i got:
#1305 - FUNCTION FACT.DATEADD does not exist 
From what I understand is that im trying to quere the db name instead of the table inside?

FACT is my DB name.

Comment: The error occurs because MySQL does not support the DATEADD function.  I've put the MySQL version of the statement into the answer above - give it a try.  COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value in its argument list (when the argument list is read from left to right).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I stll cant make it work, il have to leave at that for now. I apreciate your help.

Comment: There was a still a minor problem in the MySQL statement (second NOW didn't have parentheses after it).  You might try it again.